# Javascript defineGetter

Tags: javascript, getter

```
var a = {}; 

a.__defineGetter__('test',function() {return 5;}); 

var i ="test";
```

Is there any other way I can execute the getter besides `a[i]` (while using `var i` to do it)

**EDIT:**

I was asking ways to use `var i` to do it. I'll explain the real problem a bit better.

I am using getters on my namespace object to load modules only when needed.

```
MyNameSpace.__defineGetter__('db',function(){MyNameSpace.loadModule('db');});
```

In this case I am trying to load all modules:

```
for (var i in MyNameSpace){
    MyNameSpace[i];
}
```

I use Google closure compiler on my code, and it reduces that loop above to:

```
for(var i in MyNameSpace);
```

No modules get loaded.  I am trying to "trick" gcc into letting me load the modules.

Answer (score 7):

You can do either `a.test` or `a['test']` - both will access the `test` property of `a` and hence call the getter.

**Edit:** Ah, I see exactly what you want now. What you're doing is a clever use of getters, but unfortunately getters and setters aren't part of the current JavaScript standard (they are in ECMAScript 5 which isn't widely supported yet). Google Closure Tools seems to assume that reading a variable can't have any side-effect, which is true in the current versions of JavaScript, so I see no way to get around that. You'll have to edit the output to insert that stuff back.

Also, this isn't related to your question, but I do hope you're doing an additional `hasOwnProperty` check within the `for-in` construct.

Comment: OP seems to want to use the `i` variable. *(while using var i to do it)*

Answer (score 4):

I guess closure compiler optimizes out the code because it doesn't actually do anything but access the properties. this should work:

```
module = {}; // global
for (var i in MyNameSpace){
    module = MyNameSpace[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your module example, seems like you just want a little refactoring there.

```
var moduleNames = { 'db', 'input', 'etc' };

for ( var name in moduleNames ) {
  MyNameSpace.__defineGetter__(name,function(){MyNameSpace.loadModule(name);});
}

function loadAll() {
  for ( var name in moduleNames ) {
    MyNameSpace.loadModule(name);
  }
}
```

If the functions themselves are less trivial than that, then you similarly want to collect the functions into a handy dictionary ahead of time, then loop over those to create the getter, and loop again to create the load all function.